# Send HTML Email for Notifications

Tags: html-email

I have set the Default Mail Format in Email Configuration to HTML but email notifications are still being sent as plain text.

I have looked at the other posts regarding this issue but I could not find a definitive answer on how to get this to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the notification templates and add what ever markup you want to include.  By default, they are text only.
Design->Message Pages->Email Notifications

Comment: I have done that and the resulting emails show up as HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an add-on to ensure that system emails obey that HTML setting:

https://github.com/cld-agency/ee-html-email

Please note that if you are using any Freeform notifications, they will also need to be formatted with HTML.